# Are there mainstream RDBMS's ("databases") that do NOT optimize on the ">" or "<" symbolic operator?

Tags: sql, query-optimization, rdbms

I ran into this [article](http://hungred.com/useful-information/ways-optimize-sql-queries/) that states that this query:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN > 16
```

is slower than

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN >= 17
```

The reason for this is that

> [the query] is not optimized due to the fact that the DBMS will have
>   to look for the value 16 THEN scan forward to value 16

The second query is faster because

> This way the DBMS might jump straight away to [the] value

I have a hard time believing that mainstream RDBMS's (postgres, oracle, mysql/maria, DB2, etc) are really that "dumb" -- aren't they smart enough to optimize this difference themselves?

Can anyone confirm or deny that this is (or is not) the case on most mainstream RDBMS's?

Comment: hmm.. maybe I should have put this on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: I doubt it's a common problem.

Comment: @Marco . . . This does not sound like normal behavior.  Presumably, the statement refers to using an index.  Finding the next value after `16` really isn't that hard when using an index.  Perhaps the `=` might save a few computing cycles, but any such optimization would be swamped by almost any other consideration.  There are several other inaccuracies in that blog post.

Comment: That article is wrong in many things. `WHERE  COLUMN = ‘value%’.` is useless because the `=` does not care about wildcards. The example about the `IN` query is only true for simple optimizers like the one used in MySQL. It seems that guy has never worked with anything else than MySQL . At least Postgres and Oracle generate **exactly** the same execution plans for the two statements and have the same execution *times* on a test table with 100.000 rows

Comment: @Marco No, I don't think this belongs on Programmers.

Comment: @Marco software recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [Programmers Help Center](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) (it's the same over there as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Comment: @gnat I will delete this question *if* it is indeed a request for a software _recommendation_. However, I'm curious as to whether this is a general practice in the databases that are widely used (which I assume is a set of databases that is not in discussion). Do you have recommendation about rewording this questions so that it is not seen as a recommendation request? Or would you rather I simply delete the question?

Comment: hard to tell, I would probably ask about this at [Programmers meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions) or maybe in [Whiteboard chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21) over there

Answer (score 1):

Seems that in SQL-server `>, >=, <, <=` have the same performance. Taken from this [article](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2007/t-sql-where/).

---

> Here are the key operators used in the WHERE clause, ordered by their
>   performance. Those operators at the top will produce results faster
>   than those listed at the bottom.

```
=    
>, >=, <, <=    
LIKE    
<>
```